# Problem getting MD5 fingerprint of certificate for Google Maps API

Tags: java, android, google-maps, md5, keytool

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore. -storepass android -keypass android
```

gives me the error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: /Users/syalam/.android/debug.keystore.
```

I'm not sure how I can sign my debugkey so that I can use Google Maps. I have verified in Eclipse that this is where my debugkey is stored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see a trailing extra period in the keystore file path. It should be  "~/.android/debug.keystore" instead of "~/.android/debug.keystore."